# Hint and jump to text box

Tags: firefox, vimperator

How can I place the cursor in a text box using hinting in Vimperator?

For example, on a Google search result page, if I press `f` for hinting, the text box with the search terms is highlighted and given a hinting key but if I press that key it seems that nothing happens. Is there a way to place the cursor in the search box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just discovered the [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/index) project. Apparently it's a fork of Vimperator and the most active Vimperator developers have moved to Pentadactyl. It has the functionality described in the question out of the box.

The FAQ on the site will be of interest to Vimperator users.

> Why did Pentadactyl split from Vimperator?
>
> The reasons for the fork were mostly political, but mostly boil down
>   to the fact that the current maintainer, while making no substantial
>   contributions to the project for several years, continues to exercise
>   full editorial control while actively soliciting donations with no
>   transparency whatever.
>
> [...]
>
> What differentiates Pentadactyl from Vimperator?
>
> The main difference is that Vimperator's most active developers have
>   moved on to Pentadactyl. More qualitative changes may be found in the
>   change log, but essentially add up to what we consider more active and
>   thoughtful development. Among the most visible differences, as of
>   Pentadactyl 1.0, are more extensive Firefox 4 support, significantly
>   better startup time and completion performance, [...]

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Vimperator 3.11.3 enters insert mode after following a hint to a text box anyway, but you can also use `gi` to jump to the last used text box. Similarly `[count]gi` jumps to the `[count]`th text box.